# Error PHP "Trying to access array offset on value of type null in"

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema, al entrar a una base de datos y rescatar 5 datos, me manda error,pero antes no tenia ese problema, estuve viendo que es por la version del php, e visto tutoriales y problemas similares pero no puedo dar con la solucion.

```
 if($link->connect_error > 0){
        die('Error: No es posible establecer la conexión: [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
    }
     
    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['users']);
 

 
$extraerdato = $link->query("SELECT * FROM datos where ids=$id");
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($extraerdato);
/* Datos que se mostraran */
    
   Line 21  $rendiciones = $fetch['rendiciones'];
    Line 22 $montoporrendir = $fetch['montoporrendir'];
    Line 23 $montorendido = $fetch['montorendido'];
    Line 24 $apellidos = $fetch['apellidos'];
    Line 25 $nombre = $fetch['nombre'];
    

  if ($fetch){echo"
 

  <html lang='en'>
<head>
```

Y estos codigos me manda, antes me funcionaba bien...

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home2/darpacl/public_html/bienestar/fichero3.php on line 21

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home2/darpacl/public_html/bienestar/fichero3.php on line 22
```

ASi sucede hasta la linea 25
.....

Muuchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

- Es inseguro: no conviene mostrar mensajes de error internos y `mysqli_real_escape_string` no fue seguro en el pasado. Usaremos consultas preparadas.
- Es demasiado *optimista*: hay errores que no controlas. Vamos a controlarlo todo
- Hace evaluaciones fuera de sitio: evalúas la variable `$fetch` a posteriori. Vamos a evaluar las cosas en su sitio
- Mezclas estilos de programación, lo cual no es recomendable para la claridad del código: usaremos solamente el estilo orientado a objetos en todo, por ser más claro y menos verboso

Aplicando todo lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

```
$id=$_POST['users'] ?? NULL;
if ($id) { 
    if($link) {
        $sql="SELECT rendiciones, montoporrendir, montorendido, apellidos, nombre FROM datos where ids=?";
        if($stmt = $link->query($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt -> store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($rendiciones, $montoporrendir, $montorendido, $apellidos, $nombre);
            $stmt->fetch();
            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                $outPut=array(
                               "status"=>true,
                               "data"=>array($rendiciones, $montoporrendir, $montorendido, $apellidos, $nombre)
                             );
            } else {
                $outPut=array(
                               "status"=>false,
                               "msg"=>"No se encontraron filas"
                              );    
            }   
        } else {
            $outPut=array(
                           "status"=>false,
                           "msg"=>"Error en la consulta"
                          );
        }    
    } else {
        $outPut=array(
                       "status"=>false,
                       "msg"=>"No hay conexión"
                      );
    }         
} else {
    $outPut=array(
                   "status"=>false,
                   "msg"=>"No se postearon datos"
                 );
}
```

La práctica implementada consiste en ir controlando mediante una variable llamada `$outPut` todos los posibles problemas del código. Ante cualquier error, el valor de `status` será `false` y tendrá una clave `msg` con un mensaje descriptivo del error. En cambio, cuando haya datos, la clave `status` será `true` y los datos estarán en una clave `data`.

Ahora, puedes consumir `$outPut` de este modo:

```
if ($outPut["status"]) {
    echo implode(",",$outPut["data"]);
} else {
    echo $outPut["msg"];
}
```

*¡Tu código es kilométrico!* Gritará un programador *optimista*. Sí, pero es un código maduro, robusto y que hace **todo** lo que debería hacer un código: buscar los datos y si no los encuentra, informar de por qué no los encontró e informar al usuario sobre lo que debe hacer en ese caso.

Por eso hay tantas ramas en este código. Si falta una de ellas, el programa fallará gravemente, o dejará al usuario en una pantalla en blanco. Si en esa pantalla hay un botón por ejemplo que envía datos al servidor, el usuario le dará `N` veces, invadiendo al servidor inútilmente, hasta hartarse. ¿El problema en el fondo? Un programa demasiado *optimista* que no pensó en todos los posibles problemas. La programación *optimista* es un lastre y la red está llena de esos malos ejemplos.